# strong modifier divides h1 into grid

Tags: html, css

Title is pretty much self-explanatory... I have this html div element, and it doesn't look the way I want it to, and that happens when I resize the screen:

```
  <div class='serveMessage'><strong>Fun fact:</strong>&nbsp;over 1,259,468 american students fail every year!</div>
```

I tried removing the &_nbsp; but it still doesn't work :(

This is want I want it to look, but with bold text:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/MqRZU.jpg

This is what it looks like instead with the strong tag:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/o9Ubx.jpg

The css involved!

```
.content .serveMessage {
  margin: 0 8px;
  font-family: 'Raleway', sans-serif;
  font-size: 14px;
  color: #63827b;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  padding: 11px 0;
  text-align: center; }
```

Thank you for your assistance!

Comment: We can't figure out the problem without all the html and css. Put it in a jsfiddle.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A [text run](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-display-3/#text-run) is a valid flex item, so by failing to place the strong tag and the following text run in a common parent, you have two [flex items](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-flexbox-1/#flex-items) in your flex container:

1. a `<strong>` element
2. a text run

A text run is basically a text node that the browser has to interpret as a unit, but that doesn't have it's own semantic or container element.

You should be able to solve this by doing one of the following:

- changing the display of `.serveMessage` to something other than `flex` (say, `block`), or
- adding a containing element within `.serveMessage` so that the text run isn't flexed along with `<strong>`

The first seems preferable, but the second makes sense if you have some compelling reason to flex this class elsewhere, and this is an isolated workaround.

Comment: Indeed, wrapping the div in another one did the trick, thanks!